# nginx alias syntax

Tags: regex, nginx, alias

i'm trying to alias the location of some pics in the website using the following syntax :

```
location ~/^apple-touch-icon(.*)\.png$ {
 alias /opt/web_alpha/img/$1;
 }
```

is that right or I missied something else 
in access.log of nginx I got this message :

> "GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 142

but in the browser it shows me the index page

moreover i'm confused regarding alias and rewriting in nginx , which should I use

Answer (score 5):

server location:

```
location ~ ^/(apple-touch-icon|browserconfig|favicon|mstile)(.*)\.(png|xml|ico)$ {
    root /home/user/project/static/images/favs;
}
```

on favs dir:

$ ls -1 static/images/favs/

```
apple-touch-icon-114x114.png
apple-touch-icon-120x120.png
apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
apple-touch-icon-152x152.png
apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
apple-touch-icon-60x60.png
apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
apple-touch-icon-76x76.png
apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon.png
browserconfig.xml
favicon-160x160.png
favicon-16x16.png
favicon-196x196.png
favicon-32x32.png
favicon-96x96.png
favicon.ico
mstile-144x144.png
mstile-150x150.png
mstile-310x150.png
mstile-310x310.png
mstile-70x70.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is incorrect.  First, you need a space between the location type indicator ~ and the start of the regex.  Second, ^ denotes the beginning of the string, so /^ will never match anything.  Additionally, since you're stripping the extension from the filename, I believe nginx will end up serving the file as the default mime type, so you should probably set default_type image/png in the location:

```
location ~ ^/apple-touch-icon(.*)\.png$ {
  default_type image/png;
  alias /opt/web_alpha/img/$1;
}
```

EDIT: I misunderstood what was required.  To just change the root for anything that starts with /apple-touch-icon, use:

```
location ^~ /apple-touch-icon {
  root /opt/web_alpha/img;
}
```

That's a prefix match that won't be overridden by a regex location.

Comment: yeah it works, but it seems that my regex isn't correct as i want to capture the following patterns: 

> apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png
> apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png
> apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png
> apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png apple-touch-icon.png

  
, so what is the regex should i use to match these patterns

Comment: That regex will match all those requests, assuming they're all in the root, and not something like /images/apple-touch-icon...  Do you have another regex location above this one that would match the files first?

Comment: server {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name localhost;

        location ~  ^/apple-touch-icon(.*)\.png$ {
                default_type image/png;
                alias  /opt/web_alpha/img/$1;
        }
}   this is the configuration file content

Comment: i tried : http://localhost/apple-touch-icon.png/ and in error.log logfile : /var/www/apple-touch-icon.png/index.html" is not found

Comment: it succeeded when i tried :http://localhost/apple-touch-iconapple-touch-icon.png.png  *notice that i duplicated the pattern before .png

Comment: What file do you actually want to load for a request to /apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png?  Also, the fact that it's trying to load from /var/www makes me think you have some other location that's actually servicing the request.

Comment: i want to load the same file "apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png" but from "/opt/web_alpha/img" directory

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, edited the answer to address what you actually wanted.